# Cannot install Android Studio Bundle? "Unable To Elevate Error Message"

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android development and I am trying to install the Android Studio Bundle from: http://developer.android.com/sdk/

I downloaded it and installed JDK 8u25 from: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

I installed the JDK first and then tried to launch the android-studio-bundle-135.1641136.exe file that was downloaded from Android.com but when I run it I get the following pop up error: Unable to elevate [error: ]

Haven't even installed yet and I'm already running into issues.. please help!

Thanks sincerely for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: Here how i have solved the issue in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39701334/2215072).

Comment: This is related to **USER ACCESS** refer this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52098265/4741746)

Answer (score 21):

Actually figured it out.. stupid but I had to run the android-studio-bundle-135.1641136.exe by right clicking and doing "Run as administrator". Hopefully this will help someone else that runs into the similar issue!

Answer (score 0):

To me it served me disable the firewall and antivirus completely (in my case I use avast).
I hope they serve, Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

I had to completely uninstall my McAfee and it works now!

Answer (score -3):

Follow Following steps

1. Uninstall android SDK if you have installed any.
2. Clear your temp folder ( Goto Run type "%temp%" and delete all. It may skip few files thats ok! )
3. Convert installer file into CD image using s/w like  Magic ISO Maker, http://www.magiciso.com/download.htm
4. Either you write CD or install virtual CD drive to mount ISO file.
5. Disable your antivirus / firewall and also close all programs.
6. Then run the installer from CD-drive / virtual drive. 
   ( Right Click and RUN AS A ADMINISTRATOR)

This works 100% !

Comment: This is great if it solves the OP's problem. But it would help if you could explain *why* it works - what is the underlying problem this approach corrects. That may help people who come across this answer in the future