# Android Installation Error - Unable to elevate [error:1812]

Tags: android

I have downloaded the latest android studio **android-studio-bundle-135.1740770-windows** from the [official site](https://developer.android.com/). But when I install the downloaded application file, it starts the installer and shows it extracting and then I get the following error in a small alert window:

> Unable to elevate[error:1812]

I have also tried running the application as administrator, but no luck!

Comment: This issue is ralated to **USER ACCESS** refer this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52098265/4741746)

Answer (score 12):

Right-click on the installer > Properties > Compatibility > Run Compatibility Troubleshooter

Answer (score 10):

I am facing same issue from last 2 days

Issue is related to **USER ACCESS**  most company's have set up user account that doesn't have access to install any application they have one admin user that have all this access

So when I open setup from **admin account** It open perfectly

Solution 1 - First try to simple right click on *Android studio exe* -> Click on ***Run as Administrato***r

Solution 2 - Press shift key and  hold it -> Right Click on *Android studio exe*  -> ***Run as different user***   then enter userName and Password of Admin user it work smoothly

Comment: solution 2, worked for me, my company network team had to give password

Comment: Solution 1 was the thing for me...either way, the main issue is user access, just in different aspects

Answer (score 4):

For me it worked with compatibility for win xp

Comment: This rather reads like a mediocre comment - but not like a real answer to the question!

Comment: It's the answer I needed.

Answer (score 3):

Download it in c drive and Right click and run as administrator. I tried this and it worked for me

Comment: OP said "I have also tried running the application as administrator, but no luck!"

Answer (score 3):

for me also when I tried to install from download folder i got same error so .Just copy the android studio installation file to the Desktop you downloaded, and then Right Click and Click on Run As Administrator
it worked .

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. When answering a question that already has many answers, please be sure to add some additional insight into why the response you're providing is substantive and not simply echoing what's already been vetted by the original poster. In this case, the original poster indicated that he/she had already attempted the solution you--along with several others--are recommending.

Answer (score 1):

Check this stuffs:

- Right click your android-studio-bundle-135.1740770-windows.exe and go
  to properties and click unblock buttons if it's available.
- Make sure Firewall was Disabled and your antivirus software.
- Disable UAC.

And some blogger says this step:

Convert the installer file into a CD Image (eg using Magic ISO Maker, http://www.magiciso.com/download.htm)

2) Install from CD Drive. 
http://setup-steps.blogspot.com/2014/12/android-studio-unable-to-elevate.html

Answer (score 1):

I think that your application is on a drive other than C drive. Try and copy it from that drive and paste it to the desktop then I think it would work - it worked for me at least.

Answer (score 1):

Check Compatibility mode 
Run as Windows XP (Service Pack3)

Also check Run this program as an administrator

It works for me. If you are running Windows 10 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the installer > Properties > Run Compatibility Troubleshooter. It will recommend some settings and it will apply them as well. Then you should be able to run it.

Answer (score 0):

I followed these steps and the problem was gone:

- Disable UAC
- Reboot
- Installation (as Administrator)
- Enable UAC
- Reboot

There’s a quick way you can enable or disable this annoying window from the command line:

Disable UAC:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k %windir%\System32\reg.exe ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v EnableLUA /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

Enable UAC:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k %windir%\System32\reg.exe ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v EnableLUA /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

After you enable or disable UAC, you will have to reboot your computer for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps I took:

- Clear temp folder ( Go to Run type `"%temp%"` and delete all files. It may skip a few files that's OK!)
- Right click your android-studio-bundle-135.1740770-windows.exe and go to properties and click unblock buttons if it's available.
- Make sure Firewall was Disabled and your antivirus software.
- Finally just intall

It works 99% and you don't need to install any other software to support it.

Comment: Why 99%? What happens the other 1% of the time?

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the android studio installation file to the Desktop you downloaded, and then ***Right Click and Click on Run As Administrator***.

Comment: OP said "I have also tried running the application as administrator, but no luck!"