# Cannot install Android Studio Bundle - “Unable To Elevate [Error: ] Message”

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried all the possible solutions listed here - [Android Installation Error - Unable to elevate [error:1812]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29507394/android-installation-error-unable-to-elevate-error1812)

But none of it help. I have some Administrator Settings set up upon my PC. Does this effect the android studio installation?

Comment: What if you just download the binary archive (zip file) instead of the installation package?

Comment: @cricket_007 Hey it worked. Could you tell me the difference between both the methods?

Comment: The differences are marked on the download page. The ZIP file does not contain the Android SDK, you'll need to download that separately and probably set the paths when you setup Android Studio.