# Having an error while trying to install Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, windows-10

I am having this error when I launch Android Studio 3.2 install :

[image]

How can I solve this ?

Comment: have you tried to run it as administrator or use backward compatibility?

Comment: I ran it as admin and got the same error :)

Comment: How can I use backward compatibility ?

Comment: Try to disable antivirus and firewall.

Comment: I can't do that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Installation Error - Unable to elevate \[error:1812\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29507394/android-installation-error-unable-to-elevate-error1812)

Answer (score 1):

You can try right clicking on the installer (`exe`) `-> Properties -> Compatibility -> Run Compatibility Troubleshooter`.

Also, check if it is compatible with your CPU architecture (32 bit or 64 bit). Perhaps you have downloaded *the wrong file*.

Comment: I've ran the Compatibility Troubleshooter and still having the same error